# Transfer files between Windows and Linux machines?

Tags: samba, ethernet, file-transfer

My problem is that I need to backup the files on my Linux machine to my Windows laptop. My external hard drive died, and so backing up to an external drive is out of the question for the time being.

These are the methods I've tried:

- Samba
- Samba with Gadwin GUI
- Windows Shared Folder, Wirelessly (I can't access it, even though both machines indicate a connection)

[I don't want to try Samba again](http://linuxhaters.blogspot.com/2008/07/of-silos-and-samba.html), because it's just too complex for me -- the 15-odd tutorials I used were either incomplete or assumed too much knowledge on the part of the reader. I've spent about 8 hours trying to make it work and I give up.

I've heard that you can connect two computers with an ethernet cable. Only problem is that it's not a cross-over cable, and I don't have a router, so they would have to be directly connected with a regular rj-45 cable.

I don't want to upload files to the cloud, because I have a lot of files to transfer and want it to be speedy.

Comment: Are Winders and Linux on the same drive on Different partitions, or 2 Different drives in the same machine??

Comment: Do you have a server (for HTTP or FTP or whatever protocol you can use for transmitting and receiving (large) files) running on your linux machine?

Comment: You can use something like WinSCP or other Windows ssh / scp client to access the Linux machine after you set up an ssh server. Basic samba set-up is very simple as well. Perhaps you were looking at the wrong tutorials.

Comment: @eyoung100 They are on separate laptops. I have a Windows laptop running Windows 7 64-bit, and a Linux laptop running Mint 64-bit.

Comment: @Abrixas2 No I don't have a server, but I could install one. Which one is best?

Comment: Have you tried an [Ad-Hoc Wireless Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network)with a samba share?  Samba is the only way to turn a Windows Share into a Linux One and Vice Versa

Comment: @jw013 Could you direct me to a good tutorial for setting up WinSCP? I tried a bunch of Samba tutorials and I'm now bald.

Comment: @eyoung100 I tried an Ad-Hoc Wireless Network from my Windows laptop. Both laptops indicated they were connected, but I couldn't transfer files.

Comment: samba must be installed on top of the Ad Hoc Network as Ramesh's answer states.

Comment: Have you tried [NitroShare](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare)? It's a small app you install on the Linux and Windows machines. The apps will discover each other on the network and allow files to be "dragged-and-dropped" back and forth. (Disclaimer: I'm the author.)

Comment: @user8547 There is no general answer for that, as every protocol has advantages and disadvantages. I personally would prefer FTP with a program that implements commands like `mget` and `mput` (so there is no need to package the files before transfer, and the transfer can be done in both directions). The problem with FTP is that it requires a firewall to be configured appropriately, so that opening additional ports (for the actual data transfer) is possible.

Comment: @NathanOsman This looks ideal! I checked the Mint software manager and it's not there, so I'll have to install manually. Should I install the tar.gz on my Linux Mint 64-bit machine? Do you happen to have instructions for that?

Comment: @user8547 Add the Ubuntu Repos to Mint then use Software Manager and search.  Just keep your Mint Update Settings at the default of 2

Comment: @user8547: You *may* be able to install using the DEB - I haven't used Mint, unfortunately, so I have no idea if that will work or not. The .tar.gz is the source code, so you would then need to compile it. I think I wrote instructions for that somewhere... I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Ah, here we go: https://answers.launchpad.net/nitroshare/+question/241382#comment-0 Those instructions should hopefully work for Mint if you need them. But I'd strongly suggest trying the DEB first.

Comment: @NathanOsman Hey I just installed it on both computers and it's working. Yay! To test it I transferred a 300mb video file and it transferred in about 4 minutes. So this is perfect. I installed the .deb file using GDebi. The setup was super simple. You might want to add NitroShare as an answer below, so more people see it. And I'll choose it as the best answer.

Comment: @user8547: Awesome! Glad to hear. I'll add an answer.

Comment: You don't need cross-over cable. I was able to connect two computers with regular rj45

Comment: @tomm How did you do that? Maybe you could supply an answer below with the steps to take?

Comment: Cross-over Ethernet cables are largely obsolete as pretty much every NIC and switch supports [Auto MDI-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto_MDI-X) these days.

Comment: @Reinhart Yes, I was able to connect my two laptops using a regular ethernet cable. The connection looks solid, in that both computers indicate a connection has been made, but they don't show up in each's other's networks, so I'm not able to transfer files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NitroShare](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare) may be able to do what you're looking for. It is a small app that allows files to quickly be sent between machines on the same network.

Once installed on both your Linux and Windows machines, the two machines should automatically discover each other. Use the menu in the system tray to send a file or directory to a specific machine on the network:

[image]

Download links are available [here](https://nitroshare.net).

Comment: While this is a great program for moving a small amount of files, it's not so good if you want to move, say, 50 gigabytes of data. For that it would be better to use an ethernet connection. I tried moving a few 1gb files and it took roughly 40 minutes for each. Which is too long if you want to move 50+ gb's of data. Incidentally there are a [couple alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304362/are-there-other-applications-beside-nitroshare-to-send-files-between-computers-o) to NitroShare, but I haven't tested them, as I assume they would move files at a similar speed.

Comment: EDIT: I meant it took about 15 minutes to transfer a 1 gb file, not 40 minutes. Maybe I'm being picky, but I'd like a speedier solution to moving files across two computers.

Comment: @user8547: I've been doing some intense optimization on the application and have reached the point where NitroShare actually beats SMB on some benchmarks. If you're interested in testing the new version, there are packages/installers here: http://nitroshare.net The share boxes are missing but you can use the tray icon to send files or directories. And there is no longer a limit on filesize.

Comment: Sounds great! I'd need two computers to test it out, which I don't have right now. But I will definitely check it out at some point.

Comment: I tested the new version. One laptop was running Windows 7 Starter Edition and other was running Linux Mint 17.1. I transfered three 1gb video files and it took 45 minutes. I then transferred one 1 gb video file and it took 15 minutes. So I don't see an improvement on the earlier version as far as transfer times.

Comment: @user8547 that's very strange - are you able to get faster transfer speeds using any other methods? Are the two machines connected via wired network or are they connected via a wireless network? If using a wireless network, are both machines close to the router? The only time I was able to observe remarkably slow transfer times during testing was when the receiving machine had a reduced ability to write to disk, creating a significant bottleneck.

Comment: I tested it using wireless. It might be a problem with one of my laptops. I tested it on a Thinkpad and an HP Mini Netbook. I installed Linux Mint on the HP and tested it again today. I transfered a 1 gb mp4 video from the Thinkpad to the HP and it took 15-20 minutes. I then transferred the same file from the Netbook to the Thinkpad and it took over an hour! I did get an error message when starting Nitro on the HP: "unable to listen on port 40818". But it ran without any further error messages after that. FYI I placed the laptops right next to the wireless router when testing.

Comment: I wasn't using the internet when testing both times (if that matters).

Comment: @user8547 thanks for the info. It does sound like the netbook is responsible for part of the delay, but 15-20 minutes is still much longer than expected. Even at Wireless G speeds, 1 GB shouldn't take more than 3-4 minutes to transfer. I'll continue to do some testing around here and let you know if I make any progress or come across anything that might be a cause for the slow transfer issue.

Comment: Ok! You say that 1 gb should take no more than 3-4 minutes, so it would only take about 2.5 hours to transfer 50gb. That would be great if I can get those transfer speeds from Nitro, and I'd be happy to test Nitro again. It could just be a problem with the Netbook, which is very cheap. I'll test again when I get my hands on a better laptop.

Answer (score 8):

Please do not get discouraged by the overwhelming amount of information in setting up of `samba`. It's pretty simple as discussed [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sharing_Files_between_RHEL_6_and_Windows_Systems_with_Samba).

If you do not believe, these are the steps I did in my machine and it took me just couple of minutes to access the mount point of my RHEL machine on  the Windows machine. I assume the RHEL and Windows machine are available in the same network.

Let us go one baby step at a time and it would make your experience smoother.

**Step 1: Installation**

```
yum install samba
```

Now, we will configure the firewall to open up some ports for `samba`.

**Step 2: Firewall Configuration**

To achieve this, run the Firewall Configuration tool by selecting the *System -> Administration -> Firewall* menu option.

**Step 3: Edit the configuration file**

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file to make some changes. The only change I made was, to add the below information to the end of the file.

```
[tmp]
        path = /tmp
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        valid users = demo
```

As we can see, I am sharing the `/tmp` share and allowing the user `demo` to access the share from the windows machine.

**Step 4: Add the user**

In your Linux machine, add the local user by running `adduser demo` and then run the command `smbpasswd -a demo` and set a password.

**Step 5: Start the required services**

This is the final step and we are done.

```
service smb start
service nmb start
```

Now, login to the windows machine and from *Networks* tab you could see that your Linux share is available for you.

**EDIT**

As you had mentioned you use Mint for Linux, your steps could be something as below. The configuration file for `smb.conf` is the same as RHEL machines and the online tutorial could be accessed from [here](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3781).

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo restart smbd
sudo testparm
```

Comment: What do I do after opening up the firewall? I use Gufw. The firewall is off.

Comment: @user8547, if the firewall is off you can ignore the second step.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, but I'm going to use NitroShare. But this will be useful for other, more brave souls who want to try Samba. :)

Answer (score 4):

How do you connect to the internet? Wireless? That's slower than cable but should work if you can get an IP for both PCs.

From experience, WinSCP gives the least problems transfering files and dealing with reconnects, etc. (on Windows)

Your Linux machine probably already has ssh activated, so on Windows you only download WinSCP, enter the IP, username, password and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-over Ethernet cables are largely obsolete as pretty much every NIC and switch supports [Auto MDI-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto_MDI-X) these days. You can use a regular straight-through Ethernet cable and the NICs will just "figure it out" on their own.

If you are connecting PCs directly (without a router or other [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server), you'll need to set static IP addresses on both systems. For example, 192.168.1.40/24 and 192.168.1.41/24.

After you can ping the Linux box from the Windows box, then you can use SSH or Samba or whatever you want to actually push the files.  I specifiy pinging in this direction because Windows firewall is braindead and defaults to blocking ICMP echo requests (pings).

Comment: So I'd have to use Samba in addition? I thought if I just connected the ethernet cable to each computer then each computer would show up in each other's networks and I could navigate and move files freely between them.